# how to learn html from any free tool or simple converter

Tags: html

I am new to HTML i am looking to any good and simple tool which can help in to learn and practise html code.

it should accept html5 concepts and some css styling.
and display output on same page.

your suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: you don't need any tools beyond a text editor and an html rendering agent. e.g. internet explorer + notepad.

Comment: Yeah I know IE + Notepad. I found one good tool for which I was looking for http://toolsfree4you.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found one good tool for which I was looking for http://toolsfree4you.com